# Ignore case sensitivity keyword set

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I'm trying to ignore case sensitivity when searching for keywords on specific subreddits, using PRAW.

```
def run_bot(r, comments_replied_to):
    print "Obtaining 25 comments..."

    keywords = {"eyebleach", "eye bleach", "enough internet for today", "enough internet for the day"}
    for comment in r.subreddit('test').comments(limit=25):
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword.lower() in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
                print "Keyword found in comment " + comment.id + "!"

                posts = r.subreddit('eyebleach').random()
                print("Generated random image post from /r/eyebleach: " + posts.url)

                comment_reply = "[**Need some eye bleach?**](%s)" % posts.url

                comment_reply += "\n\n/u/eyebleacher_bot was created by [@cjgetty](http://github.com/cjgetty).\n\nThis eye bleach has been randomly generated from [/r/eyebleach](http://reddit.com/r/eyebleach)."

                comment.reply(comment_reply)
                print "Replied to comment " + comment.id + "!"

                comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)

                with open ("comments_replied_to.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(comment.id + "\n")

        print "Sleeping for 10 seconds..."
        #Sleep for 10 seconds...
        time.sleep(10)
```

In the `keywords` set, how would I go about searching for those same keywords of any case (lower, upper, mixed)?

Comment: Why can you not just ‘lower()’ the comment body

Answer (score 0):

Using the `str.lower()` method you can case-insensitively compare two strings. For example

```
a = 'sTriNg LoWeR'
b = 'string lower'
c = 'STRING LOWER'

if(a.lower() == b.lower() == c.lower()):
    print('All equal!')
```

prints `All equal!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if keyword.lower() in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
```

to

```
if keyword.lower() in comment.body.lower() and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
```

You add a **.lower()** to **comment.body** in your if statement.